# Alternating Background Color react-data-table-component

Tags: reactjs

i need to alternating the background color of react-data-table-component
this my style

```
const customStyles = {
            rows: {
              style: {
                border: 'none', // override the row height
                backgroundColor: ["#FFDDDD", "#FFF4F4"],// this the color
                borderRadius:8,
                marginTop:8
              }
            },
            headCells: {
              style: {
                backgroundColor: "#FFF4F4",
                border: 'none',
                borderRadius:8,
              },
            },
            cells: {
              style: {
                paddingLeft: '8px', // override the cell padding for data cells
                paddingRight: '8px',
                border: 'none'
              },
            },
          };
```

how can this style work to my react-data-table-component

Comment: you can call a fuction for row trStyle={getRowStyle} and based on index return the style that you need

Comment: You can refer this for more explanation https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/blob/26d07defab759e4f9bce22d1d568690830b8d9d7/examples/js/style/tr-style-table.js